# Google Calendar API: holiday event with day off property

Tags: google-calendar-api

In my app, I am getting the events from the holiday calendar of a particular country. I wonder if it's possible to distinguish between holiday in which you work and the holiday when you have day off. Eg.: Valintine day in my country is not a day off but Christmas day is.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

### This depends on the calendar

The default Google holiday calendars do not specify in the description which holidays are bank holidays (the ones where you don't work) and which are not, so there is no way to know distinguish between them.

What you can do instead is create or find a private calendar that you can import.

I don't know your region, but for example for Barcelona, the council of Barcelona offers a [public holiday calendar](https://ajuntament.barcelona.cat/calendarifestius/en/) that you can download as a ICS file and import into your calendar. I am sure that for your region you can find something similar.